# Populating a combobox in Word from Excel - stops working after Excel file is moved

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Thanks for your time! Using snippets of code gathered here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, I was able to cobble together a macro that will populate a combobox in Word from a defined range of data in an Excel file, and then get a label to print the second column from the combobox (which is too long to display in the combobox itself). So far, so good. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
'Late binding.  No reference to Excel Object required.
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlWS As Object
Dim cRows As Long
Dim i As Long
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  'Open the spreadsheet to get data
  Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("EXCEL FILEPATH")
  Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
  cRows = xlWS.Range("$A2:$B216").Rows.Count - xlWS.Range("$A2:$B216").Row + 1
  ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
  'Populate the listbox.
  With Me.ComboBox1
    For i = 2 To cRows
       'Use .AddItem property to add a new row for each record and populate column 0
      .AddItem xlWS.Range("$A1:$B216").Cells(i, 1)
      'Use .List method to populate the remaining columns
      .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = xlWS.Range("$A1:$B216").Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
  End With
  'Clean up
  Set xlWS = Nothing
  Set xlWB = Nothing
  xlApp.Quit
  'Make label print column 2 of ComboBox
  With ComboBox1
        Label1.Caption = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that when the Excel file is moved and then the Word file is closed and reopened, the comobobx no longer gets populated. Unfortunately, this needs to be a standalone Word doc that is distributable via e-mail to multiple users. Is there a way to populate the combobox so the Word document holds the data without having to refer back to the Excel file each time the doc is opened?

Thanks again!

Comment: How about having the Excel file on a network share and having the Word document look there?

Comment: Tripp: thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, the best I could probably do would be SharePoint, and then I'm not sure how the permissions would need to be managed. Furthermore, the combobox will need to be to be updated quarterly with new data by someone with even more limited skills than my own. I need to keep it as simple as possible to re-populate the combobox - preferably once per quarter withe a local file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this that I've used before is not to use Excel at all, when you send out the Word document, have it connect to a trusted web site that returns the list instead.

While I've not done this in Word, I have done it with Excel where the spreadsheet was emailed out as a blank template for filling in. A web site was used to populate reference data dropdowns. The reference data changed periodically so that was the best way to provide the freshest data while retaining an existing spreadsheet that people were familiar with.

If you are not too bothered about populating from a spreadsheet, you can of course, create a combo from code, the values for the combo could be kept in a field in Word.

Let me know if either of these is helpful & I will try to expand if needed.

Update:

You can make use of a [DocProperty Field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/field-codes-docproperty-field-HA102014613.aspx) to store the entries for your combo if you don't actually need anything else from your spreadsheet.

Create a field called `Combo Options` or whatever and put into it:

```
Option 1;Option 2;Another Option
```

Or whatever text options you want.

In VBA, you can access the fields using:

```
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Combo Options").Value
```

Then you can split the field into it's components and iterate over them to add the combo box options.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think the first suggestion will be possible. I work for an organization with extremely strict IT policies and I don't have the authority to create or edit a trusted web site. I'm not sure I understand your other suggestion. When you say "the values for the combo could be kept in a field in Word," do you mean a field in an inserted Excel sheet or some other kind of field? Also, isn't creating a combo from code what I'm already doing?

Comment: You are creating the combo via code, sure but based on the content of a spreadsheet. My suggestion is to keep the data in a [Word property field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/field-codes-docproperty-field-HA102014613.aspx).

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate your continued efforts. Unfortunately, there are two columns and 215 rows of data. Manually entering each one into the Value field of the Custom Properties tab in the Advanced Properties dialogue box is no faster than simply manually adding each one in the Drop-Down List Properties dialogue of a regular old Drop-Down List content control. Are you suggesting I put the data in an inserted Field Quick Part? In that case, what's the code to get Word to pull the data from there?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create file in user's computer with desired data? That means, it only requires first time for them to open excel file and afterwards it would read the data from .txt file.

Here is link on how to create simple file in user's computer:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/File-Path/WritingtoTextFilesUsingPrint.htm

Comment: I would appreciate if you would let me know why you downvoted my article, when I believe I provided proper answer to the question?

Comment: Robert: Thanks for your response. I did not downvote your reply. I do appreciate it; however, I think the suggestion you provided suffers the same problem as my original code. With your method, the text file is written from the Excel file, right? So end users would still need the Excel file at least once. I want to be able to email out the Word doc by itself to anyone and have the combobox remain populated. Please correct me if I am wrong. Right now I am working on the code you suggested just in case I am wrong.