# Populating a combobox in Word from an embedded Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Thanks for the efforts to answer my other question, but I have given up on trying to populate a combobox in Word from Excel. I got it to work, but the problem is that when the Excel file is moved and then the Word file is closed and reopened, the comobobx no longer gets populated. Unfortunately, this needs to be a standalone Word doc that is distributable via e-mail to multiple users. (Here's my other, unanswered question: [Populating a combobox in Word from Excel - stops working after Excel file is moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163819/populating-a-combobox-in-word-from-excel-stops-working-after-excel-file-is-mov).) So, I thought: what if I just put the spreadsheet in the Word document (via Insert>Table>Excel Spreadsheet)?

Here's what I tried:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim oleSH As Word.OLEFormat
Dim cRows As Long
Dim i As Long
Set oleSH = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat

  cRows = oleSH.Range("$A2:$B216").Rows.Count - oleSH.Range("$A2:$B216").Row + 1
  ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
  'Populate the listbox.
  With Me.ComboBox1
    For i = 2 To cRows
       'Use .AddItem property to add a new row for each record and populate column 0
      .AddItem xlWS.Range("$A1:$B216").Cells(i, 1)
      'Use .List method to populate the remaining columns
      .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = xlWS.Range("$A1:$B216").Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
  End With
  'Clean up
  xlWB.Close True
  xlApp.Quit
  Set xlWS = Nothing
  Set xlWB = Nothing
  'Make label print column 2 of ComboBox
  With ComboBox1
        Label1.Caption = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

However, I get a compile error: Method or data member not found. Word doesn't seem to be able to recognize the method ".Range" like Excel can. How can I make this work? Thanks again in advance, and if you can answer my other question please do! I'd be happy to make it work either way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to get an excel object for that embedded spreadsheet.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Tried it out. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a Word.Table to store the data in my document instead of an embedded Excel object. I initially rejected this idea because I didn't know how to do it. I was only able to find Greg Maxey's code for populating from a Word.Table in a *separate* document. (The code in question can be found [here.](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/populate_userForm_listbox_or_combobox.html) Scroll down to the section External Data Sources: Word table.)

However, after much tinkering around, I discovered that to populate a ComboBox from a Word.Table in the *same* document as the ComboBox you are populating, all you have to do is modify Maxey's code a bit. Simply change `Set sourcedoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="D:\Data Stores\sourceWord.doc", Visible:=False)` to `Set sourcedoc = Me` and remove the line `sourcedoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges` so the Doc being used won't be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect from your other question (to which I've tried an answer by the way), that you are creating the xlWs object with late binding which I think is why Word can't make sense of the Excel Range.

You might want to switch to a reference and early bound object?

Comment: Thanks to both Tripp and @JulianKnight . I tried switching to early binding and now there is a problem with the method .Names. I get a compile error: Method or data member not found. How do I get the new instance of Excel to grab the necessary cell range in the Word OLE table? Here's my code (sorry, struggling with mini-Markdown):

Comment: `Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Set xlapp = New Excel.Application
Dim xlbook As Word.OLEFormat
Dim Listarray As Variant
Dim bStartApp As Boolean
Dim cRows As Long
Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        bStartApp = True
        Set xlapp = New Excel.Application
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With xlapp
        Set xlbook = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat
        Listarray = xlbook.Names("$A2:$B216").RefersToRange.Value
    End With`

Comment: Also, if I use early binding, will the document work for people who haven't got the MS Excel 14.0 Object Library reference installed?